# Xamarin Android application database

Tags: c#, android, sql, xamarin

What is best practice using databases (sql) for android aplication written in c#?

My first idea is to create database in sql, than create web application with entity framework to read data via json, or write to database  with web requests.
Is it good idea? Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends.. if you really need a SQL Server database for centralized data you can do as you said. I only suggest to expose database throught REST Web Api so you can easy access from Xamarin with standard HttpClient.

If you only need a device persistence you can look at SqlLite: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/

or you can look at REALM DB here: https://realm.io

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ill have microsoft server so i will have sql database. I will use REST Web Api as u said.